# MVC 3 changing /Register/Event/1?name=channel-news-asia to /Register/Event?name=channel-news-asia

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

Currently, I have http://localhost:xxxxx/Register, showing a table retrieve from the database.

eName               eLink                          fWidth    fHeight
channel-new-asia    http://www.channelnewsasia.com/    1024  768      **Register**

Now, the Register link is like http://localhost:xxxxx/Register/Event/1?name=channel-news-asia, how do I make it http://localhost:xxxxx/Register/Event?name=channel-news-asia

Answer (score 1):

By default MVC uses this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //Parameter defaults
        );
```

You put parameter with name 'id' into the request somwhere on the page. So, URL contains 'id' param. You need to use another name (not 'id'), or you should change default.